# cannot find "count" in scope

Tags: swift

please help me!!

```
func updateApps()
{
    guard let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int else{
        for x in 0 ..<  count {         //**cannot find "count" in scope**
            if let task = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "task_\(x+1)") as? String{
                Apps.append (tasks)
                return              
            }             
        }
    } 
}
```

*please help me!!*

Comment: Unrelated but consider that there is `integer(forKey` (returns a non-optional) and `string(forKey`. Never use `value(forKey` unless you mean KVC (you don’t).

Answer (score 1):

As **@vadian** mentioned `integer(forKey` returns default as `0`, So you don’t need `guard` statement to check for nil values.

```
 func updateApps()
    {
    
         let count = UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "count")  
            for x in 0 ..<  count {        
                if let task = UserDefaults().string(forKey: "task_\(x+1)") {
                    Apps.append (tasks)
                      
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `integer(forKey` returns a non-optional with default value 0. Delete `guard` and the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because you are using guard. The else is being called when the `UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int` value is **nil**

You can try this instead

```
func updateApps() {
        
        if let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int {
            for x in 0..<  count {
                if let task = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "task_\(x+1)") as? String{
                    Apps.append(task)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to use guard then you can use this

```
func updateApps() {
        
        guard let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int else {
            return
        }
        for x in 0..<  count {
            if let task = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "task_\(x+1)") as? String{
                Apps.append (task)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```